# Merging filter-generated output with static JSON object using jq

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I'm trying to use `jq` to iterate over some delimited text files, and generate objects from the rows.

I also want to add some "static" objects (`json` shell variable in the example below) to the generated results.

I've come up with the below solution, which *does* produce the output I want. But, because I'm not very confident in jq, every time I solve a problem with it, it feels like a monkey banging on a typewriter rather than a carefully crafted answer. So, I'm imaginging this could be incorrect.

**data.txt**

```
apple|fruit
Tesla|car
sparrow|bird
```

Test (bash shell):

```sh
$ json='[
  { "object": "love", "type": "emotion" },
  { "object": "Ukraine", "type": "country" }
]'

$ jq --slurp --raw-input --argjson extra "$json" '
split("\n") |
map(select(length>0)) |
map(split("|") | {
  object: .[0],
  type: .[1]
}) as $data |
$data + $extra' data.txt
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "object": "apple",
    "type": "fruit"
  },
  {
    "object": "Tesla",
    "type": "car"
  },
  {
    "object": "sparrow",
    "type": "bird"
  },
  {
    "object": "love",
    "type": "emotion"
  },
  {
    "object": "Ukraine",
    "type": "country"
  }
]
```

Is this efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's more efficient but you could shorten the code using `--raw-input` or `-R` without `--slurp` or `-s` to linewise read in a stream of raw text (no need to split by newlines), the `/` operator to do the "column" splitting within a line, and `reduce` to successively build up your final structure, starting with your "static" data.

```sh
jq -Rn --argjson extra "$json" '
  reduce (inputs / "|") as [$object, $type] ($extra; . + [{$object, $type}])
' data.txt
```

If you want the "static" data at the end, add it afterwards and start with an empty array:

```sh
jq -Rn --argjson extra "$json" '
  reduce (inputs / "|") as [$object, $type] ([]; . + [{$object, $type}]) + $extra
' data.txt
```

Comment: `jq` never ceases to amaze me. Today I learned about "dividing" two strings with the `/` operator. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
jq -nR --argjson extra "$json" '
    [inputs / "|" | {object:.[0], type:.[1]}] + $extra' data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for this variant. I gave this a vote, but accepted @pmf's answer since their answer was "first", is very similar, and also yields the correct results.

Comment: I know two answers are very similar, the major difference being I didn't use `reduce` in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[inputs / "|" | {object: .[0], type: .[1]}]
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/XkDdy9-lBq

Or

```
reduce (inputs / "|") as [$obj, $typ] ([]; .+[{$obj, $typ}])
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/5N3M-pfJIR